# MEAN.js - what does this piece of javascript mean?

Tags: javascript, meanjs

Good sirs: in the boilerplate MEAN.js code, I see this...

```
<form name="articleForm" data-ng-submit="update(articleForm.$valid)" >
```

yet the controller says this...

```
$scope.update = function() {
    var car = $scope.car;
    car.$update(function() {
        $location.path('cars/' + car._id);
    }, function(errorResponse) {
        $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
    });
};
```

So what is happening with `articleForm.$valid`?

I assume it is a boolean, but it looks like `$scope.update` doesn't have an argument to access that boolean.
and simply passing FALSE to a javascript function normally doesn't stop that function from executing...

Comment: maybe the documentation for angular's form will help. Look for validation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: nah - no mention of the phenomena I'm pointing out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **form.$valid** field indicates if all the fields of the form contain valid input.

In this case the update function does not take any parameters so sending the **form.$valid** to it does not change anything.

Comment: ah - so I found an imperfection in the MEAN.js yo crud-module generator! Thanks

Comment: you can use the flag if you need to, maybe that was their intention. :)

Comment: OK, I was just checking if there was some Angular magic happening that changed the rules of a normal Javascript function.